# Using 'nodeunit' module in Typescript

Tags: typescript

DefinitelyTyped has a [type definition file for nodeunit](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/nodeunit/nodeunit.d.ts).

In it, there is

```
declare module 'nodeunit' {
    export interface Test {
    }
}
```

How do I use it in my code? It seems the lowercase spelling causes some trouble.

None of the following works:

```
/// <reference path='../nodeunit.d.ts' />


// cannot find name 'nodeunit'
function testX(test: nodeunit.Test){}

// syntax error
function testX(test: 'nodeunit'.Test){}

// signature with implementation cannot use string literal type
function testX(test: 'nodeunit.Test'){}

// cannot find name 'NodeUnit'
function testX(test: NodeUnit.Test){}
```

The first version can be made to work if I just remove the quotes from the module declaration: `declare module nodeunit`.

Comment: Did you include a reference to it as described in the [typescript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries)?

Comment: @BlakeMumford Yes, I have the "reference path". That works well with other modules, or if I manually change the quoting/casing of the module name in the type definition.

Comment: How did you get the typescript definition? Through tsd? Is the path to the definition file correct?

Answer (score 1):

`declare module 'nodeunit'` Means we have declared it as an external module. You can import it using:

```
import nodeunit = require('nodeunit');
```

And compile with `--module commonjs`.

Also as a tip you can see sample usages in the test file for the definition, in this case : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/nodeunit/nodeunit-tests.ts

## UPDATE

Based on:

> But I don't want to use require. The file does not contain any implementation, only type definitions

I am assuming you are declaring an external module yourself. In this case you would do:

```
declare module "mine" { 
    import nodeunit = require('nodeunit');

    function testX(test: nodeunit.Test);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. But I don't want to use `require`. The file does not contain any implementation, only type definitions, so there is no need to require it at runtime.

Comment: Then do `declare module "mine" { import nodeunit = require('nodeunit')}` just to get its type information

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use that "mine" module in my `testX` function signature?

Comment: I see. So I can only use this type definition for external modules? For now, I only have internal modules. Maybe I'll revisit this later.

Comment: Yes, the way its defined you can only use it for external modules